# How can I catch the controller/action values of a request before dispatch?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Zend Framework:

```
I have the following url  /base/url/[number]/[string] 
OR                        /base/url/action/controller/param/value
```

I want in the case of `/base/url/[number]/[string]` to transform it to
/base/url/controller/a/action/b/id/[number]/name/[string]
The a and b are constants (i.e. each time I see a number in the place of the action, I use the same values).
Where can I catch the action and controller values before they are being dispatched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recieve action and controller in Controller Plugin in routeShutdown()  (once after route is selected) or in preDispatch() (before every controller dispatch). I guess you would use routeShutdown. You have Request accessible, so you can set controller and action to anything at all..

[How to write plugins](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Route to handle that kind of routes, and have them dispatched to the correct controller and URL.

For example:

```
$router = $front->getRouter();
$router->addRoute(
    'my_route',
    new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
         ':number/:string',
         array(
              'controller' => 'your_controller',
              'action' => 'your_action'
         )
    )
);
```

Comment: So, How do I extract the number from the url? I need it to be 
/16/something -> /question/show/id/16

Comment: Just use in your controller $this->_getParam('number') and $this->_getParam('string') whatever you put in :number you use that to extract, for example if your route is:
:page/:name
You extract using $this->_getParam('page') and $this->_getParam('name').